# How to apply =ARRAYFORMULA() to a reversed numbered list in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, numbered-list

| No. | Name | Employment status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (insert formula here | Sample Name | Type of Employment |
| 5 | John | Full-time |
|  | Mary | Resigned |
| 4 | Jack | Part-time |
| 3 | Tim | Contract |
|  | Jane | Dismissed |
| 2 | John | Full-time |
| 1 | Larry | Part-time |

So the logic should be that the formula would output a no. in a reversed numbered list format in column 1, and for those who are "Dismissed" or "Resigned" in column 3, the formula would skip them and the next numbering would be a follow-up from the previous no. instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply =ARRAYFORMULA() to create a reversed numbered list in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73231442/how-to-apply-arrayformula-to-create-a-reversed-numbered-list-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(MMULT(N(C2:C8={"Resigned","Dismissed"}),{1;1}),"",MMULT(N(ROW(C2:C8)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(C2:C8))),1-ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2:C8,{"Resigned","Dismissed"},0)))))`

- answered by @Jos Woolley in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73231442)

Answer (score 3):

**Formula for you**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(C2:C="Current",INDEX(SORT({COUNTIFS(INDEX(SORT({C2:C,ROW(C2:C)},2,0),0,1),"Current",ROW(C2:C),"<="&ROW(C2:C)),ROW(C2:C)},1,0),0,1),""))
```

[image]

---

**Edit: Include more than one label**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF((C2:C="Full-time")+(C2:C="Part-time")+(C2:C="Contract"),COUNTIFS((C2:C="Full-time")+(C2:C="Part-time")+(C2:C="Contract"),1,ROW(C2:C),">="&ROW(C2:C)),))
```

**or**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF((C2:C="Full-time")+(C2:C="Part-time")+(C2:C="Contract"),COUNTIFS((C2:C="Full-time")+(C2:C="Part-time")+(C2:C="Contract"),">0",ROW(C2:C),">="&ROW(C2:C)),))
```

**or**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2:C,{"Full-time","Part-time","Contract"},0)),COUNTIFS(MATCH(C2:C,{"Full-time","Part-time","Contract"},0),">0",ROW(C2:C),">="&ROW(C2:C)),))
```

**or**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2:C,"Full-time"&"Part-time"&"Contract"))*(C2:C<>""),COUNTIFS(SEARCH(C2:C,"Full-time"&"Part-time"&"Contract")*(C2:C<>""),">0",ROW(C2:C),">="&ROW(C2:C)),))
```

[image]

**Function References**

- [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)
- [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en)
- [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en)
- [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en)
- [ISNUMBER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296?hl=en)
- [SEARCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154?hl=en)
- [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)

Comment: Hi @Theza! I've updated the question to include more than one label to apply the exception from numbering. Would you please help to see if your current formula would be able to cater to this update? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @qazamy I updated my answer more.. hope it works

Answer (score 3):

Try `COUNTIF()` like-

```
=Arrayformula(IF(C2:C<>"Current",,COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, ROW(C2:C), ">="&ROW(C2:C))))
```

> ***Edit:*** After OP's comment and updated data try below formula-

```
=Arrayformula(IF(C2:C="",,IF(RegexMatch(C2:C,"Resigned|Dismissed"),,COUNTIFS(C2:C,"*",ROW(C2:C), ">="&ROW(C2:C))-(COUNTIFS(C2:C,"Resigned",ROW(C2:C), ">="&ROW(C2:C))+COUNTIFS(C2:C,"Dismissed",ROW(C2:C), ">="&ROW(C2:C))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Harun24hr! May I know how do I go about using this formula if "current" is switched to more than a single label? E.g. "Full-time", "Part-time", "Contract"?

Comment: Based on data we have to add more condition. As per your sample data this was post.

Comment: Hi Harun24hr! I've revised my initial sample data.

Comment: Do you have more keyword or current keywords are fixed?

Comment: Hi Harun24hr! Any workaround that doesn't involve regex? We're using an in-house solution that's similar to Google Sheets but not quite. So custom functions and =regex() are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative: Use Custom Function

You may also create a custom function using Google Apps Script like the one below:

```
function customFunction(range) {
  var out = [];
  var count = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= range.length-1; i++) {
    (range[i][1] != "Resigned" && range[i][1] != "Dismissed") ? count++ : count;
  }
  for (i = 0; i <= range.length-1; i++) {
    if ((range[i][1] != "Resigned") && (range[i][1] != "Dismissed")) {
      out.push([count]);
      count--;
    } else {
      out.push([""]);
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

### Usage

You may rename the customFunction name to whatever you want. To use the customFunction, you just need to input the following syntax:

```
=customFunction(B3:C9)
```

Comment: Hi PatrickdC! Unfortunately, we're using an in-house solution that's similar to Google Sheets but not quite. So custom functions are not supported.

Comment: Hello @qazamy! My bad. I did assume that you are using Google Sheets based on the tag. I merely presented an alternative when it comes to solving the issue using Google Apps Script since it is easier to modify (in my opinion) when adjustments are required.