# How to apply =ARRAYFORMULA() to create a reversed numbered list in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

The formula has to be input on cell A2. The logic should be that the formula would result in the following cell (from cell A3 downwards) outputting a no. in a reversed numbered list format in column 1. And for those who are "Resigned" or "Dismissed" in column 3, the formula would skip them and the next numbering would be a follow-up from the previous no. instead.

We're using in-house software that's similar to Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel so certain functions/formulas like REGEX and custom functions are not supported.

| No. | Name | Employment status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (insert formula here | Sample Name | Type of Employment |
| 5 | John | Full-time |
|  | Mary | Resigned |
| 4 | Jack | Part-time |
| 3 | Tim | Contract |
|  | Jane | Dismissed |
| 2 | Jonathan | Full-time |
| 1 | Larry | Part-time |

This post is a repost from this [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73045107) as the solutions weren't applicable to this issue, unfortunately. So I'm looking for alternative solutions from those answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply =ARRAYFORMULA() to a reversed numbered list in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73045107/how-to-apply-arrayformula-to-a-reversed-numbered-list-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(MMULT(N(C2:C8={"Resigned","Dismissed"}),{1;1}),"",MMULT(N(ROW(C2:C8)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(C2:C8))),1-ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2:C8,{"Resigned","Dismissed"},0)))))`

Note that the oft-seen technique of replacing the upper cell reference in the range passed with a reference to the entire column (for example, `C2:C`) would here not be advisable. If such flexibility is required, suggest you create a dynamic Named Range.

Comment: This works! Any way to indent it so that the numbering starts from cell A3 when the formula is input in cell A2 instead?

Comment: It dosent go all the way down can adjust it? stops at `C8`

Answer (score 1):

can't be simpler:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((C2:C="contract")+(C2:C="part-time")+(C2:C="full-time"), 
 COUNTIFS(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C, "Contract", "time"), "*time", ROW(C2:C), ">="&ROW(C2:C)), ))
```

[image]

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work on our in-house software, unfortunately. It works on Google Sheets though.

Answer (score 0):

**Paste this** formula in `A2`

```
= {"Count" ; ArrayFormula(IFNA(IF(B3:B="",,VLOOKUP(B3:B, FILTER({ B3:C, SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:B),1,COUNTA(B3:B),-1) }, C3:C<>"Resigned",C3:C<>"Dismissed"),3,0)),""))}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Osm. My bad on cell A8, I've renamed that to be a unique name. For the formula, it has to be inserted in row 2 as users might insert new rows above row 3.

Comment: The numbering is supposed to be:

 | No. | Name | Employment status | 
 | Count | Sample Name | Type of Employment | 
 | 5 | John | Full-time | 
 |  | Mary | Resigned | 
 | 4 | Jack | Part-time | 
 | 3 | Tim Contract | 
 |  | Jane | Dismissed | 
 | 2 | Jonathan | Full-time | 
 | 1 | Larry | Part-time |